# Find ID of a selectmenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, drop-down-menu

How can I get the name of the select tag?

I have several select menus. I can retrieve the submitted options. However, I would like to get the name, or even better, the ID of the select tag that holds the options.

Sample HTML:

```
<div id="prodAttributes_2">
<form id="attributesubmit">
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
<div role="heading" >Options:</div>

<select name="Memory" id="4">
<option value="3">16 mb</option>
<option value="4">32 mb</option>
</select>


<select name="Model" id="3">
<option value="6">Premium</option>
<option value="7">Deluxe</option>
</select>

</fieldset>
</div>
<input type="button" id="submitme" value="send" />
</form>
</div>
```

**Solved Fiddle:** [`JSFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/whitehat/huRQF/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `this.id` within the `each()`.

Note you can get the `name` with `$(this).attr('name')`

I've forked your [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/FUNkH/1/)

Comment: THANK YOU!!! the id is indeed the one i need. i go accept your answer,but Dan's and Fabrizio's are also correct so i give them a vote-up.I have to say that Dan made the alert better as you lol.Once again...Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
var name = $(this).attr("name");
```

to your `$('select').each` call:  http://jsfiddle.net/xPGUE/

Answer (score 1):

in your fiddle, where you get the alert

```
 alert('Value: ' + selectedOption.val() + ' Text: ' + selectedOption.text());
```

you can access to the name or id of the option using

```
 selectedOption.attr('name') 
 selectedOption.attr('id')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('select').each(function() {
   alert($(this).attr('name'));
});
```